# How to get list of ordered items in ASP.NET MVC4 form post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

HTML5 offline ASP.NET MVC4 application allows to enter order quantities for customer.

Ordered item codes and quantities are not passed to Order method.
In code below Order method Result parameter value is null.
How to get ordered item codes and quantities in Order method?
How to post only items which whose ordered quantity is greater than 0 ?
Product list is big and unordered products can not posted.
I can switch to ajax, jquery and MVC4 Web API if this is reasonable.

Controller:

```
public class OfflineOrderController : ControllerBase
{
    public class OrderedItems
    {
        public string Id;
        public decimal Quantity;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Order(string customerId)
    {
        return View(new MobileOrderOrderViewModel(customerId));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Order(string customerId, IEnumerable<OrderedItems> Result)
    {
      ... save order to database
        return new ContentResult() { Content = "Order received" };
    }
}
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="~/MobileOrder/Manifest">
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var product in Model.Products())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@product.Id</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@product.Id" />
                        <input type="number" name="Quantity" min="0" max="10000000" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Send order">
    <input type="hidden" name="customerId" value="@Model.CustomerId" />
}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the techniques that Phil Haack described in the following blog post?
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

In short, you can use something like the following. It's better if you make the Products a property instead of a method call.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Length; i++) {
  <tr>
     <td>@Model.Products[i].Id</td>
     <td>
         @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Products[i].Title)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Products[i].Quantity)

     </td>
  </tr>
}
```

This will create html elements with the "Products" prefix. In order to make sure that it is model bound properly, you can use something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Order(string customerId, [Bind(Prefix = "Products")] IEnumerable<OrderedItems> Result)
{.....}
```

**Disclaimer:** No code was tested when answering this question; it was all typed in right here.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Product list is big and only few products are ordered. How to post only ordered products whose quantity is non zero ? Is it possible and reasonable or should MVC4 Web API and javascript used for this ? How to send non-zero quantities with product ids to controller ?

Comment: I posted related question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695779/how-to-post-ordered-items-without-timeout-to-controller