# How to post ordered items without timeout to controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

HTML5 offline ASP.NET MVC4 application allows to enter order quantities and submit order for customer.

Product list rendered in browser contains about 4000 products.
Only few products are ordered for particular order.

Using code below request times out. Browser posts all products. Request takes too much time and is probably terminated by httpruntime ExecutionTimeout

Server error log shows that all posted data is received.
It looks like MVC model binder requires too much time to create product list from posted data.

How to fix this ? How to post only ordered items whose quantities are entered or other idea ?
I can switch to ajax, jquery and MVC4 Web API if this is reasonable.

Controller:

```
public class OfflineOrderController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Order(string customerId)
    {
        return View(new MobileOrderOrderViewModel(customerId));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Order(string customerId, [Bind(Prefix = "Products")] IEnumerable<OrderedItems> Result)

    {
      ... save order to database
        return new ContentResult() { Content = "Order received" };
    }


    public AppCacheResult Manifest()
    {
        return new AppCacheResult(new[] { 
            Url.Content("~/Image/Icon/favicon")
        });
    }

}
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="~/MobileOrder/Manifest">
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count; i++)
        {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model.Products[i].Id</td>
                    <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Products[i].Id)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Products[i].Quantity,
                    new { type = "number", min = 0 })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Send order">
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.CustomerId)
}
</body>
</html>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MobileOrderOrderViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    public List<OrderedItems> Products { get; set; }

 public MobileOrderOrderViewModel( string customer ) {
    CustomerId = customer;
    ... populate Products property from database
    }

}
```

Model:

```
    public class OrderedItems
    {
        public string Id;
        public decimal Quantity;
    }
```

**Update2**

Using code from Imrans answer I created API controller to receive ordered products:

```
    public class OrderController :ApiController
    {

        public HttpResponseMessage Post(string customerid, [FromBody]List<OrderedItems> products) {
  ....
   }
}
```

Debugger shows that products are posted but products parameter is empty list.
How to pass selected product list to Web API ?

Code used for posting is:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var BASE_URL = '@Url.Content("~/")';
        $("form").submit(function (ev) {
            var elementsToSend = [];
            ev.preventDefault();
            var quantityElements = $("input.quantity").filter(function (index, element) {
                if ($(this).val() != 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $.each(quantityElements, function (index, element) {
                var productIndex = $(element).prevAll()[1];
                var productIdElement = $(element).prevAll()[0];
                elementsToSend.push(productIndex);
                elementsToSend.push(productIdElement);
                elementsToSend.push(element);
            });
            var dataToPost = $(elementsToSend).serializeArray();
            $.post(BASE_URL + "api/Order?" + $.param({
                customerid: $("#CustomerId").val()
            }), dataToPost);
            return false;
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I'd suggest paging, you use ajax to call the records and you set it to always return, at max, say 1000 records and a bool if there's still more or no. You display those 1000 you just received, and if the bool is true, call the function again until it's false and keep adding the new results to the already displaying ones.

Comment: @Danicco Page with 4000 items appears after few seconds and is hopefully cached in html5 offline application cache for order entry without internet. Customer orders few items from whole 4000 items. I dont understand how dividing 4000 items to 4 pages can solve this. Paging only makes things more complicated without any benefits.

Comment: @CameronTinker How to post only selected products ids and quantities ? Should javascript used to filter only items with filled quantites or is there other way ?

Comment: @Andrus When you post something from the browser, the control is in client's hand. Doing anything on the server is too late as the browser would have already sent all 4000 items. So the trick is to use javascript to restrict the items sent back to the server. So, yes, Javscript should certainly be used.

Comment: @Andrus Oh my bad, I misinterpreted the question. The issue is because you're essentially sending 4000 fields to the server all at once, and that can be fixed with a simple javascript to generate the hidden fields with the proper names only when the user selects (or types more than 1) that product, so the server only receives a handful of IDs to process.

Comment: @ImranRashid How to filter this in javascript. Should view changed so that all items have same name for easy javascript array processing (if yes, how to implement this in Razor?) or is it reasonable filter current html which has unique names for every row? I updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is what I think your view should look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model.Products[i].Id</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="Products.Index" value="@i"/>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Products[i].Id)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Products[i].Quantity, new { @class="quantity", type = "number", min = 0 })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Send order">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.CustomerId)
    }

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("form").submit(function () {
                var elementsToSend = [];
                var quantityElements = $("input.quantity").filter(function(index, element) {
                    if ($(this).val() != 0) { return true; }
                    else{ return false;}
                });
                $.each(quantityElements, function (index, element) {
                    var productIndex = $(element).prevAll()[1];
                    var productIdElement = $(element).prevAll()[0];
                    elementsToSend.push(productIndex);
                    elementsToSend.push(productIdElement);
                    elementsToSend.push(element);
                });
                elementsToSend.push($("#CustomerId")[0]);
                var dataToPost = $(elementsToSend).serializeArray();
                //send elementsToSend via ajax
                $.post("/OfflineOrder/Order", dataToPost);
                return false;
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Order(string customerId, List<OrderedItems> products)
{
    .....
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Great. I tried to use this code to pass product list to Web API controller but it receives empty product list. How to pass product list to Web API ? I updated question.

Comment: I posed this as separate question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711501/how-to-passordered-product-list-to-asp-net-mvc4-web-api

Answer (score 0):

You can try AJAX to reduce the load:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var data = $(this).serializeArray().filter(function (k, v) {
        // Filter data based on order rule
    });
    // Send AJAX!
    return false;
});
```

Bear in mind, this only hijacks the default HTML form behavior. It can be superseded by turning off JavaScript.

EDIT: Make sure you are using the Controller / C# naming conventions. Else, binding may not work.

```
orderedItems.push({ Id: items[i].Id, Quantity: items[i].Quantity });
var data = JSON.stringify({ customerId: $("customerId").val(), Result: orderedItems });
```

There are fancier ways to do list comprehensions using `filter` but what you have makes sense to me.

Finally, in your `Order` POST action, it is a good idea to return a `JsonResult`.

Comment: It is not necessary to use Ajax. You can filter the items through Javascript and do a straight POST without using Ajax

Comment: True, you can just `remove` input elements out of the DOM. But, I recommend using AJAX. It is super-expensive to reload this entire form.

Comment: @beautifulcoder Thank you. How to filter rows using javascript? Currently every row element has unique namd and id, should this changed? I updated question and provided two ways. Which is best way to filter ? I'm targeting to android tablet and apple iPad so javascript is probably turned on always.