# How to pass products and quantities to ASP.NET MVC4 Web API from form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

ASP.NET MVC4 applications allows to enter ordered product quantities and passses them to 
Web API controller.

Controller receives empty product list as product parameter. Debugger shows that data is posted.
How to refactor view so that products can passed to Web API ?

View:

```
@inherits ViewBase<MyApp.MobileOrderOrderViewModel>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Products.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model.Products[i].Id</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Products[i].Id)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Products[i].Quantity, new { @class="quantity", type = "number", min = 0 })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Send order">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.CustomerId)
    }


<script>
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var BASE_URL = '@Url.Content("~/")';
        $("form").submit(function (ev) {
            var elementsToSend = [];
            ev.preventDefault();
            var quantityElements = $("input.quantity").filter(function (index, element) {
                if ($(this).val() != 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $.each(quantityElements, function (index, element) {
                var productIdElement = $(element).prevAll()[0];
                elementsToSend.push(productIdElement);
                elementsToSend.push(element);
            });
            var dataToPost = $(elementsToSend).serializeArray();
            $.post(BASE_URL + "api/Order?" + $.param({
                klient: $("#CustomerId").val()
            }), dataToPost);
        });
    })
</script>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MobileOrderOrderViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    public List<OrderedItems> Products { get; set; }

 public MobileOrderOrderViewModel( string customer ) {
    CustomerId = customer;
    ... populate Products property from database
    }

}
```

Model:

```
    public class OrderedItems
    {
        public string Id;
        public decimal Quantity;
    }
```

WebAPI Controller:

```
    public class OrderController :ApiController
    {

        public HttpResponseMessage Post(string customerid, [FromBody]List<OrderedItems> products) {
   // Why  products.Count() is 0 here ?
  ...
   }
}
```

**Update**

I changed code according to answer. alert() shows that string is in format described in answer but products parameter is still empty.

chrome shows that request type is

Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;

but  buffer contains json string. Maybe this confuses Web API. How to fix ?

```
        $.each(quantityElements, function (index, element) {
            var productIdElement = $(element).prevAll()[0];
            var product = {
                id: $(productIdElement).val(),
                quantity: $(element).val()
            };
            elementsToSend.push(product);
        });

        var dataToPost = JSON.stringify(elementsToSend);
        $.post(BASE_URL + "api/Order?" + $.param({
            customerid: $("#CustomerId").val()
        }), dataToPost);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your data serialization.

In order to be properly binded it has to be in the following format:

```
"products" : [ 
              {"id":1, "quantity":20},
              {"id":5, "quantity":100},
              ...
             ]
```

In your case the following code produces a wrong output:

```
 $.each(quantityElements, function (index, element) {
                var productIdElement = $(element).prevAll()[0];
                elementsToSend.push(productIdElement);
                elementsToSend.push(element);
            });
```

If I'am not wrong it produces something like:

```
[ 
   {name:"id[1]", value:1},
   {name:"quantity[1]", value:20}
   {name:"id[2]", value:5},
   {name:"quantity[2]", value:100}
   ...
]
```

You can fix this by something like:

```
$.each(quantityElements, function (index, element) {
      var productIdElement = $(element).prevAll()[0];
      var product = {
           id : $(productIdElement).val(),
           quantity : $(element).val()
       };

       products.push(product);
 });
```

Than instead of `serializeArray()` use `JSON.stringify(products)`

**UPDATE**

Try posting it to the server with:

```
$.post(BASE_URL + "api/Order?" + $("#CustomerId").val(), products);
```

P.S in this case you don't have to `stringify` products object because `.$post` supports plain objects as well

Comment: Thank you. I changed code according to answer but problem persists. buffer contains json but request type is www-urlencodeded, maybe this confuses web API I updated question.

Comment: @Andrus Try using $.ajax and pass "application/json" as the content-type.

Comment: @Alex Art. I tried to pass plain object as .post second parameter. In this case `undefined:` if posted in post buffer and no data is posted.

Comment: @ImranRashid Thank you. $.ajax with `application/json` worked. Is it OK to replace for loop with foreach in view ? This makes code a bit simpler. In this case probably names are not indexed, can form data parsing simplified? How to show progress indicator in center of screen during request ?

Comment: @Andrus Yes, now that index is no more required, you can safely use foreach loop. You can show the spinner when doing the ajax request. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807408/showing-loading-animation-in-center-of-page-while-making-a-call-to-action-method